# Countable unions of closed, second-countable spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and let $Y_n$ be a sequence of compact, second countable subspaces of $X$. Can we conclude that

$$\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty Y_n}$$

is second-countable too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: let $X=\beta N$ and $Y_n=\{n\}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$: $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, and each $Y_n$ is certainly compact and second countable, but the smallest cardinality of a base for $X$ is $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}=|\wp(\Bbb N)|$. [Mrówka $\Psi$-spaces](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/) are another example: each is locally compact and Hausdorff, each has a countable dense set of isolated points, and none of them has a countable base.